# Best strategy for video security, package or separate DVR?

Tags: security

I am considering setting up a video monitoring system for home security. This would include cameras mounted both on the house itself and in 2-3 locations on the grounds. I had originally planned to just get a "canned" system which has the 3 main components: cameras, cables and a DVR together. I have read it can get tricky getting extension cables for canned systems.

However, I have recently heard that you can buy the components separately, getting your own DVR and that this supposedly can be better because the canned DVRs may be mediocre quality. Supposedly by buying your own DVR you can get a much higher quality DVR for the same money.

Does anyone have experience with this to state whether it is better to get a canned security system, versus an a la carte approach?

Note: I am very technically capable (have electronics workshop etc), so simplicity is not a factor.

Comment: I suspect this will be closed as a "shopping question"... By definition buying components gives you more opportunity to trade off features against price. Whether that's better or not depends on your own knowledge about these systems and exactly what products you are comparing, at what prices.

Answer (score 1):

I purchased all of my cameras and DVR a la carte and found it to be a bit cheaper and you get what you wany. Ebay is your friend for finding the parts and components necessary.

There are many options available for DVR systems now. In this day and age you will definitely want something that is HD capable. There are a lot of systems out there called hybrid DVRs that can record both analog and IP video. This would allow you to have some cameras that are lower resolution in areas you don't require quality and also the capability to use HD (720p, 1080p) cams in others. These could even be wireless cameras.

[AliExpress](http://www.aliexpress.com/), [SecurityCamera2000](http://www.securitycamera2000.com/) are also good sources for equipment.

I purchased some cheap (400TVL) dome cameras off ebay, and replaced the sensors with 2MP (720p) Sony IP cameras and saved a bundle. Since you are tech savvy, I think you would enjoy tinkering with different cameras and camera technologies. Searching for "Board Cameras" on ebay, ali, or securitycamera2000 will yield many results that will enable you to customize your system to you specific needs.

Just keep in mind, most of this stuff comes directly from china so it may be hit and miss on quality and take 3-30 days to arrived, but I have yet to be burned...

Good Luck!